# Angular/NodeJS: Unable to Upload Image to AWS S3 from client side

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, ng-file-upload

I have a Anggular/NodeJS application where I am able to upload an image to AWS S3. I have tried the NodeJS part and it works when tested with Postman, but I am unable to get the image from the client side. How would I get the image and successfully load it onto S3? I am using the AWS-sdk and Multer on the NodeJS part, and for Angular the ng-file-upload directive.

View:

```
   <div ng-if="!user.imageurl">  
       No Image here 
         <img ngf-src="$scope.picture" style="width:100px; height:100px">
           <input ngf-select  
                  id="file"  
                  type="file"  
                  ng-model="$scope.picture"  
                  ngf-accept="'image/\*'">
           <button type="button" ng-click="$scope.uploadImage($scope.picture)">Upload Image</button>    
    </div>
```

Client Side Server:

```
 .factory('UploadFac', function($http) {  
    var urlBase = mainsite + "image"; 
    var _UploadService = {}; 

    _UploadService.uploadProPic = function(image) { 

    var fd = new FormData(); 
    fd.append('file', image); 

    return $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlBase,
            data: fd,
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    });
   }
 return _UploadService; 

})
```

Controller:

```
//export image upload 

exports.uploadImage = function(req, res) {
   aws.config.update({accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY, secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_KEY});
    var s3 = new aws.S3({signatureVersion: 'v4'});
    var key = 'Give your Image a name';
    var image = req.files[0];
    var s3_params = {
Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
Key: key,
ContentType: image.mimetype,
ACL: 'public-read',
Body: image.buffer
     };

   return s3.putObject(s3_params, function(err, data) {
if(err) {
  res.json({ status: 500, success: false,  message: err});
} else {
  res.json({
    status: 200,
    success: true,
    message: 'Image uploaded',
    data: 'https://'+ S3_BUCKET +'.s3.amazonaws.com/' + key
  });
}
 });
 };
```

Comment: Use `Upload.upload()` or `Upload.http()` from the ng-file-upload.

Comment: You can also upload directly to s3 from client side ng-file-upload without the need of node.js in the middle.

Comment: @danial,  I am following your example of the direct to S3 upload at https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload/wiki/Direct-S3-upload-and-Node-signing-example. For the var aws, how or where do I get the path to the necessary credentials. I do apologize I'm not that familiar with using S3 with Node.